# Telerik Report Stored Procedure call: The expression contains object 'myobject' that is not defined in the current context

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I'm very new to telerik reporting. Please check my issue below.

I have created a telerik report using designer. This report calls stored procedure to retrieve the data and binds to chart.

I'm getting following error message when I generate the report via report viewer.

```
  "The expression contains object 'dtScan' that is not defined in the current context".
```

I have already added all required report parameters (input parameters). Actually this 'dtScan' is not an input parameter. It is a one of the data table field and using inside my stored procedure. I'm sure that there is no issue on my stored procedure. It is working perfectly when I design the report (means that when I set stored procedure to report via design wizard).

As I mentioned, I'm getting this error message when I generate report via report viewer and as well as preview window (please see the attached images below).

[image]

[image]

Please looking forward your help to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to understand the problem. The reason is because of 'temporary  table. I have temporary table inside my stored procedure and return data from temporary table.

Please refer ​this link: [http://www.telerik.com/forums/temporary-table-in-stored-proc​](http://www.telerik.com/forums/temporary-table-in-stored-proc%E2%80%8B)

Hope this helps others!